My Lubuntu system changes the keyboard input automatically
The keyboard layout stays Qwerty (us) but it Capitalizes the letters and mouse clicks doesn't work in some scenarios . I tried everything from changing keyboards to reinstalling the OS and other versions of it but the problem stays the same . If I reboot the pc then it works for 10-15 minutes but becomes like this again .
